# Authorship Disputes and Contributions in Collaborative Research Projects

Tags: publications, ethics, paper-submission, authorship

**Background**

My colleague (referred to as X) and I collaborated on two research endeavors, termed A and B. While our overarching goals aligned, our specific inputs varied due to individual commitments, relocations, and different tasks.

**In project A**, I mainly coded, while X was responsible for writing. Despite our efforts, this work wasn't accepted due to a reviewer's concern. Later, we aimed for another venue. At this stage, X proposed modifying the model's architecture. I was skeptical since the reviewer's feedback didn't point to this aspect. Nevertheless, X went ahead, and after achieving promising results, I rejoined X to conduct the necessary benchmark experiments (the new design had a slight variation from the old model). We then tried submitting this revised work elsewhere. When faced with another rejection, I proposed an arXiv upload, but X was keen on a lower-tier conference. I assisted with the draft transfer to a new format, and X, skilled in LaTeX, managed most of the restructuring. We received positive feedback this time, necessitating more experiments during rebuttal, which I handled, while X drafted the rebuttal.

However, the point of contention arose during the camera-ready submission. Despite my efforts to discuss this phase for a week, X took the lead, finalized the paper as the first author, and submitted it without my prior knowledge. Confronting X led to his justification that his decision to try a new venue and the paper's subsequent modifications warranted his primary authorship, sidelining the need for a mutual discussion and equal authorship.

**Project B**

X has decided to remove my authorship from project B, (which again was a reiteration from a previous work in which we contributed equally). I never questioned X's lead in B, since B required a complete overhaul of our previous work and required more advanced hardware to run the experiments which I simply did not possess. In spite of this, I helped X in whatever way possible, benchmarking other methods on different data and suggesting edits to the manuscript. It is to note that by this time I had joined a new job and was having trouble juggling both. I agree that for B my contributions were limited, but to say that I do not deserve to be an author was deeply disconcerting.

How should I deal with this situation, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are separate issues with each of these situations.

Project A obviously had a bumpy road to publication. I can sympathize with your colleague's apparent desire to be done with the paper. I don't agree with the apparently unilateral decision to take first authorship (or the revision/submission without your approval) though. But I would not die on that hill as I think your only recourse would be to contact the journal/conference and express that you did not consent to publication. This would be bad for all involved. Again, I do not think this was an ethical thing for your colleague to do, but I see limited practical recourse.

I think Project B has some more subtlety to it. Your colleague clearly feels that you have not contributed enough to warrant authorship. You clearly feel that you have. You should discuss this plainly. I feel that the courteous (and ethical) thing to do on their part would be to offer you the opportunity to contribute enough to remain an author. I suspect though, and this is just speculation, that this is your colleagues way of indicating that they do not want to continue collaboration.

This does feel somewhat underhanded. However, if you really haven't contributed (and have not made significant effort to contribute) why do you feel that you should be an author?

My advice would be to move on and find others to work with. At best, this person is just a poor communicator. At worst they are actively trying to screw you over.

Answer (score 0):

You are both in agreement that you are both coauthors of Project A. This means in particular that it can only be published with both of agreeing with the particulars such as author order. You do have the option of contacting the conference and informing them that you did not agree to the publication, which ought to lead to the paper being withdrawn.

For Project B the situation is different: If you aren't actually a coauthor, X doesn't need your agreement for anything here. However, if you are a coauthor, well, then you are. (Of course in reality there are grey areas.)

My recommendation would be to involve a trusted third party as mediator.

Another potentially effective although ethically dubious approach would be to use the threat of raising a fuss over Project A in order to blackmail X into recognizing your contribution to Project B.